# Moen kitchen faucet replacement

Tags: water, kitchens, faucet, valve

I had a leaky kitchen faucet so I got a new Moen 87557 from Homedepot. I was able to install everything up until I was ready to connect the faucet to the water outlet. The old faucet had a 3/4" (I think) and new one has 1/2" inlet and my water outlet has a pipeline which doesnt fit into the new Kitchen faucet intake. Am very much a rookie, so please help me with suggestions on what can be done about this? PLease find attached the photos.

[image: Thats the intake of the new faucet]

[image: Thats the outlet from the valve]

Comment: go to back home depot and ask for an adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the LFA124 adapter from hone depot and i was able to connect it properly.